# To play embedded video using url in iOS

Tags: ios

I have integrated amp player in iOS so it's playing finely a mp4 video but i want to play embedded video in that. So how can we do that? If not possible using MPMoviePlayer, so any other solution, Please give kms that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can play mp4 file using `MPMoviePlayerController`. something like,

your viewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;

}
-(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender;
@end
```

Your viewController.m file should be like,

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 -(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender{
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
 pathForResource:@"audioTest" ofType:@"mp3"];
 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:
 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
 [audioPlayer play];
 }
 -(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender{
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
@"videoTest" ofType:@"mov"];
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController 
 alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
 [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:NO];
 }
 @end
```

you can refer [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_audio_video.htm) for more details

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yes, I knew that i can play mp4 video in mpmoviePlayer but here i don't want that. I want to play embedded video url in that.

Comment: what do you mean by embedded video url ?

Comment: youtube video which is not having any extension (Like as "https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=J6vIS8jb6Fs")

Comment: Ok, but i am also calculating playing time suppose if pay time reaches to 5 sec so i will do some thing task. So it's possible using web view.

Comment: I dont have idea about that but i think it should possible!! Google it you will get answer :)